# Sublime Text 3 stuck trying to reload files

Tags: sublimetext3

When sublime text is opened, it immediately asks shows the message " has changed on disc, would you like to reload it?" Either clicking Reload or Cancel instantly freezes sublime and I must force quit the app. These files always open at launch and prevents me from using sublime in any way. Tried clearing cache and restarting, but no effect. Thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: you can also fix this by upgrading to build 3127 - https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1443

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed by deleting sublime_session files under Sublime Text 3/Local

Comment: Full file path on Windows is C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local